# What are the translations of these IT-related terms: app, service, consulting?

Tags: translation, terminology

What are the right translations of these IT-related terms into (simplified) Chinese:

- app (as in iOS apps)
- service (as in application service)
- consulting (as in IT consulting)

Is there a reliable dictionary that includes such specialized contemporary terminology?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**What are the right translations of these IT-related terms into (simplified) Chinese:**

> app --> 应用
>
> service --> 服务
>
> consulting --> 咨询

**Is there a reliable dictionary that includes such specialized contemporary terminology?**

> [The CKJ Dictionary](http://www.cjk.org/cjk/samples/ceterm.htm)
>
> [Dict.cn -- an online Chinese/English dictionary](http://dict.cn/en/)
>
> *[Others]*

Comment: It's interesting how they abbreviated 移动软件应用程序 to just 应用. I would've expected something like 移软.

Comment: @deutschZuid My guess is that 应用 is a translated word of the English word "app".

Comment: @deutschZuid, 移动 is for mobile, 软件 is for software, 应用 is for application and 程序 is for program. So, 移动软件应用程序 means mobile software application program.

Comment: @deutschZuid, Precisely, "应用软件" stands for "software application", and "应用" is the app, "软件" is the software.

Comment: Guys I know what this means. I just let you know you my expectation. I never doubted the validity of the answer!

Comment: @deutschZuid Sorry for the late response. I don't know if you have figured that out, but I would like to say that some words are born on the Internet, created by somebody (e.g. some media), and accepted by most of the people (Internet users) and most of us don't really know why are those words called in that way, we just understand it and other people understand it too. Hence, "应用" is one of those words. We usually differentiate "应用" and "应用程序/应用软件" according to those APP which are developed for mobile and those are developed for traditional PCs.

Comment: Yes. IBM publishes dictionaries of exactly this sort. Initially, they were made for their own internal use. They wanted to sell IBM machines, and now much more services, in all languages, so there it was.
In time their sales and their political lobbying people came to see that these were a valuable gift. Ask your IBM person for the one in the language you need.

Answer (score 1):

- **App** - colloquially, this is often simply "APP" (frequently capitalized and pronounced /eɪpiːˈpiː/, not /æp/, despite its etymology). 应用[程序] is used too, though.
- **Service** - 服务 or 业务. Depends somewhat on the situation, but in the extremely broad sense the word is often used, 业务 often makes more sense. However, "microservice" is 微服务.
- **Consulting** - 咨询 or 顾问. Usually the former to describe companies and the latter to describe individual professionals, though there's some overlap (and sometimes used together as 咨询顾问).